# OpenErp: How to filter sale orders by a functional field?

Tags: filter, odoo

I have a little problem.

I have a wizard where i have all sale orders BUT i need to have only those that have balance less than 0 (zero). Balance field is a functional field so domain is not working.

Any ideeas how i can resolve this ? I need to be able to select those sale orders that have balance less than 0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fields of type `function` or `compute` you have two options:

1) Either give the field the attribute `store=True` so that the calculated values are saved on the database

2) Or even better provide your own `search` method that will do the searching and apply the domain.

How you will do the above depends on the version of Odoo that you are using. Take a look at the documentation on `odoo/fields.py` on field class. Use the **search** parameter on the field definition:

> ```
>     One can define a field whose value is computed instead of simply being
>     read from the database. The attributes that are specific to computed
>     fields are given below. To define such a field, simply provide a value
>     for the attribute ``compute``.
>
>     :param compute: name of a method that computes the field
>
>     :param inverse: name of a method that inverses the field (optional)
>
>     **:param search: name of a method that implement search on the field (optional)**
> ```